# Javascript scroll on an element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to emulate scrolling on an element with a zoom in button.

I've gotten this to fire, but the zoom is not what I am looking for. It distorts my canvas element.

```
    var currentZoom = 1.0;

    $('#zoom-in-button').click(function() {
        $('.vis-network canvas').animate({ 'zoom': currentZoom += 200 });
    });
```

Using jquery and jquery-ui latest.

---

**UPDATE:**
When I say animate distorts it... I mean it totally ruins it.
[image]

Comment: Isn't 200 A LOT to add?

Comment: @PoulBak iterations like 1 and .1 were hardly, if at all, noticeable

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use:

```
currentZoom += 2.0
```

Zoom values have the value 1 as 'normal'.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know. I have just given that a try. It seems I must scroll rather than zoom.